# how to optimize this code? I want to fix the DeadlineExceededError issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to extract data from datastore. I am relatively new to programming, so printing out results on a page seems easiest for me. Unfortunately, most of the time (not always!), I get the following error. Could you please help me out?

Error message:

```
500 Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
```

Logs:

http://pastebin.com/C2LQCArn

DeadlineExceededError

My understanding is that my query is too slow:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

How do I speed it up?

```
class ExpData(db.Model):

        # According to Datastore Admin, there are 20,557 entities in this model.

        created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
        username = db.StringProperty(required=True)

        task1n = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task1a = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task1c = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)

        task2n = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task2a = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task2c = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)

        task3n = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task3a = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task3c = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)

        task4n = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task4a = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
        task4c = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)

        q1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        q2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)

        ecus = db.StringProperty(required=False)


    class Viewer(Handler):
        def get(self):

            test = ExpData.all().order('-created')
            expDataDict = {}
            expDataList = []
            for entity in test:

                if (entity.q2 == "-1") or (entity.q2 == ""):
                    continue
                else:
                    expDataList.append(entity.created)
                    expDataList.append(entity.username)
                    expDataList.append(entity.ecus)
                    expDataList.append(entity.q1)
                    expDataList.append(entity.q2)
                    expDataList.append(entity.task1c)
                    expDataList.append(entity.task2c)
                    expDataList.append(entity.task3c)
                    expDataList.append(entity.task4c)
                    expDataDict[entity.created] = {}
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["username"] = entity.username
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["ecus"] = entity.ecus
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["q1"] = entity.q1
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["q2"] = entity.q2
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["task1c"] = entity.task1c
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["task2c"] = entity.task2c
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["task3c"] = entity.task3c
                    expDataDict[entity.created]["task4c"] = entity.task4c

            self.render("viewer.html", otherDict = expDataDict)
```

Many thanks for help.

Comment: Yeah, this won't work.  You shoudl look at your access patterns and see how you can cache, or precompute the output as a cache.  Trying to display all entities via query will get worse as you add more.  Try using cursors as per the answer below.

Comment: @TimHoffman -  
Thanks. It is data from my experiment - I want to extract it for data analysis. I don't anticipate to collect any more data. Could you recommend any other way to download it? Maybe as a CSV?

Comment: If your just trying to get the data for later analysis. Consider using the remote api shell and pull it down using cursors and save locally.  That way you don't have to deploy new code and it can take ages (as long as you use batches, say 1000 items at a time) as it's not a front end request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of deferred.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

And from your deferred task create the extract and send it to you as an email.

For deferred tasks the request limit is 10 min. If you extract completes within 10 minutes , you are good.

Pseudocode :

Create a module extract_task.py for the background task.

```
''' extract_task.py '''

from StringIO import StringIO
from google.appengine.api import mail

def extract():
    output = StringIO()
    test = ExpData.all().order('-created')
    for entity in test:
        # Just extracting 3 fileds per row for the example.
        output.write('%s,%s,%s\n' % (entity.created, entity.username, entity.ecus))

    mail.send_mail(sender="youremail@example.com",
                   to="Albert Johnson <youremail@example.com>",
                   subject="Extract",
                   body="""
Extract attached.
""",
                  attachments=[('extract.csv', output)])
```

Write up a new handler:

```
from extract_task import extract # import the module cretaed above.
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

class Viewer1(Handler):
    def get(self):
        deferred.defer(extract)
        self.response.write('Exatrcat will be emailed to you soon.')
```

app.yaml

add the following entry to the builtins section of your app.yaml:

```
- deferred: on
```

And the following entry to the handlers section of the same file:

```
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
    script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
    login: admin
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, thanks! Could you, please, briefly outline how I would go about emailing myself the results?

Comment: Edited my answer to add more details. Take a look. ***Code not tested

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thank so much for your help!

Comment: @polished
Emailing it to yourself is just one of the options you have. You can  even write the extract to the blobstore and get it from there.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to add these conditions to your query instead of running them after retrieving the result `(entity.q2 == "-1") or (entity.q2 == "")`. Second, you should look into pagination of the results in order to view that much data. You should look into [Query Cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Query_cursors) instead

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import db

# class Person(db.Model): ...

# Start a query for all Person entities
people = Person.all()

# If the application stored a cursor during a previous request, use it
person_cursor = memcache.get('person_cursor')
if person_cursor:
  people.with_cursor(start_cursor=person_cursor)

# Iterate over the results
for person in people:
  # Do something

# Get updated cursor and store it for next time
person_cursor = people.cursor()
memcache.set('person_cursor', person_cursor)
```